# What's the difference between using these different ways to compare two characters?

Tags: javascript, string, hex, ascii

In the source code here: https://github.com/pillarjs/parseurl/blob/master/index.js#L96

```js
if (typeof str !== 'string' || str.charCodeAt(0) !== 0x2f /* / */) {
    // ...
}
```

The author uses `str.charCodeAt( 0 ) !== 0x2f` to check if the string starts with a slash(/), I want to know the differences between the different ways below:

```js
str.charCodeAt( 0 ) === 0x2f;

str.charCodeAt( 0 ) === 47;

str.startsWith( '/' );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern environment, they're all the same.

I suppose someone might use the `0x2f` version if they're extremely familiar with the [hexidecimal character codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) of ASCII (more so than with the decimal indicies).

One potential problem with the `startsWith` version is that it requires `String.prototype.startsWith`, which does not exist in ancient environments like Internet Explorer. Using `charCodeAt` will slightly be compatible with the random user.

IMO, a clearer looking alternative while maintaining backwards compatibility would be:

```
str.charAt(0) === '/'
```

or

```
str[0] === '/'
```